# How to sort a list of lists by an item of the sublist that is a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to sort a list of lists by 1 item that is a float.
Problem is, using sort(list, itemgetter(n)) sorts the floats as strings and the output is not what i expect.

```
list1 = [('1','1',"9999"),('1','1',"9998"),('1','1',"9998.777"),('1','1',"9995111"),('1','1',"110000")]

list2 = sorted(list2, key=itemgetter(2))

print(list2)
```

actual result :

```
[('1', '1', '110000'), ('1', '1', '9995111'), ('1', '1', '9998'), ('1', '1', '9998.777'), ('1', '1', '9999')]
```

Expected result :

```
[('1', '1', '9998'), ('1', '1', '9998.777'), ('1', '1', '9999'),('1', '1', '110000'),('1', '1', '9995111')]
```

Comment: `print(sorted(list1, key=lambda x: float(x[2])))` ?

Answer (score 2):

It sorts them as strings because *they are* strings. `itemgetter` just returns `x[2]`, as it is. What you want is a function that takes a x and returns `float(x[2])`. So, just use `key= lambda x: float(x[2])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the float conversion, you can map a function on it:

```
list2 = list(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], float(x[2])), list1))
```

Then your line `list2 = sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(2))` will work as expected.

Otherwise, you can use `sorted(list1, key=lambda x: float(x[2]))` as Rakesh mentioned in the comments, to sort by 2nd element casting float type on it.